# dygraph don't load local css file

Tags: css, dygraphs

I have been building a dygraph chart and needed to set labels on the right side of chart as on many examples on dygaphs pages. Labels default to be on left. I have a dygraph js and css file on the same folder as my index.htm file and I have declared css source on my htm file: rel="stylesheet" src="dygraph.css"

I noticed that editing css file has no effect on chart. Dygraph seems to somehow load css from some external source or somehow generate it from js. I don't know. I tested this by copying all html code from this simple example from dygraph page (http://dygraphs.com/tutorial.html) to htm file and it works without css file. Just js file is needed.

Has somebody figured out how to get dygraph to read local css file?

I finally overcome my problem by overriding default css by putting edited css strait into my index.html head as internal css.

Answer (score 0):

rel="stylesheet" src="dygraph.css" is not enough. type="text/css" is missing. So the complete line should look like:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="dygraph.css">
```